# Idiomatic Way to Return an Invalid Struct in Go

Tags: go, idioms

I am writing a ray-surface collision function that needs to return small structs (`Collision` contains some information about the collision). Currently I am returning the struct by value because I do not need to adjust or share the contents of `collision`. However, sometimes the ray will not actually collide, so my function signature currently looks like:

```golang
func (scene *Scene) GetFirstCollision(ray *Ray) (Collision, bool)
```

Where the boolean is false when there is no collision. However, I do not know what value the `Collision` should take when there is no collision. If it were a pointer, I would just return `nil`, but it isn't, so should I return `Collision{}`? If the overall more idiomatic way is just to return a `*Collision` and return `nil` when it does not exist, I am open to that too, I just can't think of a case when I would ever need a pointer to the collision.

Comment: Both are fine. Use whichever works for you. If pointers don't make sense in your case, you shouldn't switch using to pointers just for the rare case when there's no useful value to return. `Collision{}` is completely fine.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "more idiomatic" to use `nil` to indicate "no collision", nor to use a pointer type just for that purpose. However, "what is more idiomatic" is a purely subjective, opinion-based question, making it off-topic for SO.

Comment: A third option is to make `Collision{}`, i.e., the zero-valued `Collision`, represent "no collision". That seems likely to be easy to do—the stuff inside an initialized `Collision` is likely to have at least some nonzero member, even if it's just an index number into an external array (just don't use the zero'th member of the array for anything and you're good). Then you don't need the separate `bool` return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my humble opinion...

- Unless returning a pointer is important to your use case, continue to use the return type of `(Collision, bool)` and simply do `return Collision{}, false` when there is no collision.
- If returning the collision as a pointer **is** important to your use case, simply return a `*Collision`, where the `nil` return type signifies "no collision", as you have described.

It is desirable, to my knowledge, for ray-tracing to be quite performant, so you may have a genuine reason to prefer the first option.

Comment: The first is semantically clearer so I would reverse that. Unless it *is important* to return a *pointer*, it would be better to return a value and a `bool`.

Comment: @Adrian Yes I think your wording makes more sense - edited.

Comment: Thank you for the quick input. I do very little programming, this is just a fun little math project, so I'm never sure of the proper style and what is/isn't really okay, so this is very helpful.

Comment: If performance is an issue, as it usually is for graphical things like ray tracing, then switching to pointers may provide quite a bit of a performance boost when you think about how many times a struct is copied. Every time a struct is a parameter, a returned value, retrieved from an array or map, or you're ranging over a list, the entire struct is copied. If it's a pointer, only the address is copied and that's much smaller/faster.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Yes, it's definitely faster to pass around a pointer.  I think the potential problem with that though is the number of heap allocations.  I imagine, if this is for ray tracing, then the method will likely be called frequently.  That is a lot of heap allocations and a lot of GC workload to use pointers.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark [It's probably already a heap allocation.](http://www.agardner.me/golang/garbage/collection/gc/escape/analysis/2015/10/18/go-escape-analysis.html) From the article: "The basic rule is that if a reference to a variable is returned from the function where it is declared, it “escapes” - it can be referenced after the function returns, so it must be heap-allocated."

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Hmmm I don't think that is what that article is saying - try running `go run -gcflags '-m -l'` on [this code](https://play.golang.org/p/-08GLSZBQz_Q) versus on [this code](https://play.golang.org/p/-p1pl3JmF-6).  The latter has no escapes.  The segment you quote is, I believe, discussing what we observe in the first code example only.